# The 72 hour visa-free transit through China on a dual citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, china, dual-nationality, visa-free-entry

I was reading this helpful guide on transits and read the following in regards to the Pearl River Delta visit from Hong Kong.

> Applicants must hold a single citizenship passport; dual citizenship passport holders are not allowed.

Can anybody confirm this? I've only seen this here. Don't have access to Timatic.

Source: https://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/visa-application/china-visa-exemption.htm#tour

PS — In my case the passports are from Spain and the Dominican Republic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Dual citizen" in this case means someone who also holds Chinese nationality, as they must hold a mainland passport, Mainland travel permit (for Hong Kongers, Macanese and Taiwanese) or Taiwanese national ID card.

That said, if caught as a dual national, your Chinese nationality is gone, except for those with *hukou* in Hong Kong (not sure about Macau and Taiwan). 
**Even there, however, you're obliged to use a Chinese document**

If you're not a Chinese citizen, this doesn't apply to you.

So if you have a Spanish and a Dominican passport, you can use your Spanish one to enter visa-free for a 72-hour transit (by air) or to get a 3 or 5-day visa on arrival (by land)

Comment: Super interesting. Question, so a Chinese citizen who is also American, EU can travel to Hong Kong but not Guandong / Guangzhou unless they have these documents per your observation? Would love to see the source for that.

Comment: The source is that the mainland doesn't even allow dual citizenship - meaning you legally lose Chinese citizenship the Moment you take on another citizenship. HK, being autonomous with some laws of its own, does allow dual citizenship.

Comment: Actually Hong Kong doesn't recognize it -- if you register your foreign citizenship at Wanchai Immigration you'll lose your Chinese citizenship. But on the other hand, HK doesn't take a proactive stance on dual citizenships like Mainland China does,

Comment: @TheGrouchHK I meant "allow" as in "doesn't Strip a dual citizen of their Chinese citizenship"

Comment: Why would they single out dual citizens from China in this communication? Very confusing even though I see what you're saying.

Comment: @Crazydre That's exactly what they'll do if you show HK Immigration a foreign passport if they have you listed as a Chinese HK citizen...

Comment: Wow, @Crazydre may have actually revealed key info. Besides the 5 days you get in Shenzhen, can you also get 5 days in Guangzhou? Where do you go through? Can you do this without a tour guide?. Tks!

Comment: @ovatsug25 I stand corrected. Double-checked with Timatic, and the 144-hour transit arrangement when arriving and leaving by air through Guangzhou has been abolished, and it's now 72 hours